# Java Swing: Do something while the key is being pressed

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, key-bindings, onkeypress

Im using a `KeyAdpater` to get the events and the method `addKeyListener` and works fine. The problem is that when a press the key, the action ocurrs only once and not while its being pressed, **after** 3-4 secs holding down the key the action occurs all the time which is what I want.

I'd want to know if there is good way to do the action all the time the key is being pressed **from the very begining**, not after 3-4 seconds holding down.

I thought on the next solution, but maybe there is already an implemented way to do it:

```
public abstract class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
    private boolean isPressed = false;
    private int pressedKey = 0;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(isPressed)
                keyPressedAction(pressedKey);
        }
    });    

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(!isPressed){
                pressedKey = e.getKeyCode();
                t.start();
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         if(isPressed && e.getKeyCode()==pressedKey)}
             isPressed = false;
    }

    public abstract void keyPressedAction(int key);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had good success with this by using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener, and start a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) on key press, and then stopping the Timer on Swing release. You can differentiate between the key press and release by passing the correct KeyStroke object into the bound component's [InputMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) using the `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int keyCode, int modifiers, boolean onKeyRelease)` method found here: [KeyStroke API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html). If the boolean parameter is false, the input will respond to key press, and the converse if the parameter is true.

For a quick and inelegant example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyBindingEg extends JPanel {
   private static final String UP_KEY_PRESSED = "up key pressed";
   private static final String UP_KEY_RELEASED = "up key released";
   private static final int UP_TIMER_DELAY = 200;
   private static final Color FLASH_COLOR = Color.red;

   private Timer upTimer;
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();

   public KeyBindingEg() {
      label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(label);

      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
      KeyStroke upKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);
      KeyStroke upKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true);

      inputMap.put(upKeyPressed, UP_KEY_PRESSED);
      inputMap.put(upKeyReleased, UP_KEY_RELEASED);

      actionMap.put(UP_KEY_PRESSED, new UpAction(false));
      actionMap.put(UP_KEY_RELEASED, new UpAction(true));

   }

   private class UpAction extends AbstractAction {
      private boolean onKeyRelease;

      public UpAction(boolean onKeyRelease) {
         this.onKeyRelease = onKeyRelease;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         if (!onKeyRelease) {
            if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
               return;
            }
            System.out.println("key pressed");
            label.setText(UP_KEY_PRESSED);

            upTimer = new Timer(UP_TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  Color c = label.getBackground();
                  if (FLASH_COLOR.equals(c)) {
                     label.setBackground(null);
                     label.setForeground(Color.black);
                  } else {
                     label.setBackground(FLASH_COLOR);
                     label.setForeground(Color.white);
                  }
               }
            });
            upTimer.start();
         } else {
            System.out.println("Key released");
            if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
               upTimer.stop();
               upTimer = null;
            }
            label.setText("");
         }
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      KeyBindingEg mainPanel = new KeyBindingEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyBindingEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @Pete I tried this code from bottom to up and vice versa, I can't found out words in comparing ..., up to your alley, aaaach