# KeyBindings will randomly stop working

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

I am trying to make a game where we can move around, and I already issued a problem for it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274327/keystroke-and-keylistener-wont-work). Someone then told me to tru KeyBindings, and I managed to create this small Keyboard class, to get general information about the keys, but I keep getting the same problem as before: it only works during a few seconds, and then it just stops working, without throwing any exception.

Here is the code:

```
public class Keyboard {
private static final HashMap<Integer, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
private static final int[] alphabet = new int[] {KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_P};

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static void start(JPanel component) {
for(int c : alphabet) {
        keys.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(c, 0, false).getKeyCode(), false);
        component.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(c, 0, false), c);
        component.getActionMap().put(c, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pressed:" + c);
                keys.put(c, true);
            }
        });
        component.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(c, 0, true), -c);
        component.getActionMap().put(-c, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Released:" + c);
                keys.put(c, false);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static boolean isPressed(int key) {
    return keys.get(key);
}
```

}

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example demonstrates how you are using the class and the problem it generates

Comment: Okay I can do it in a few hours